# External Clock Input to Microchip Microcontroller NOT Gate?

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I'm using a PIC24FJ256GB110 connected via SPI to a CAN Bus Controller chip MCP2515. The MCP2515 requires a crystal connected to it but has a Clock Output pin for driving a connected MCU. So I was going to connect the Clkout from the MCP2515 to the MCU.

My question is that in the [osillator data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39700c.pdf) for the PIC24F family of processors it shows this external clock connection with a NOT Logic gate in the circuit. I usually get parts from farnell but struggling with what it is I need for this NOT gate. Can it be any general NOT Gate or is it something more specific then that, like a buffer or some sort of impedance magic? Or is it as simple as a single NOT gate used to "clean" up the clock signal?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a gate to clean up the waveform (or just to indicate that there is a logic output driving the input)- it would not generally be used if you were employing a clock oscillator nearby the MCU such as [this](http://www.foxonline.com/pdfs/FXO_HC73.pdf) one (photo from Digikey.com).

[image]

You could use a ST gate such as this [one](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/NC/NC7S14.pdf), but usually it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

These ([Pierce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator)) oscillators are commonly built around CMOS ports for their high impedance. Usually a [74HC04](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT04.pdf), [4069](http://www.cmos4000.com/cmos/4069.html) will do the job. Use the remaining ports as output buffer so do do not unnecessarily load the oscillator itself.

A Schmitt Trigger is **not** useful for a Pierce oscillator.

[Use of the CMOS Unbuffered Inverter in Oscillator Circuits - Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/szza043) Especially check the chapter on *Practical Design Tips*

Comment: That download link was very slow for me, an alternative is http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/szza043

Comment: The 74HC04 is NOT a good candidate for Pierce oscillators. Use 74HCU04 (buffered versions can do strange things because of the extra delays). The CD4069 is okay because it has only a single stage.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was reading about (un)buffered in the TI document I linked, but I was unable to figure out which devices go with that. Turns out the HC **U** was the answer.

Comment: @alexan_e changed the link.